# How to display full response raw with pyhon requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I try to get full response from site with python requests, but there is an issue.
Website has a hidden reponse after close html tag . I can see it in burpsuite, but I don't know why when I print request.text it display only everything in html tags.

Comment: Is it possible there is JS running on the webpage that is appending to the page?

Comment: As far as i know there can be PHP in backend which generate text after these tags